# EJB Queries with WHERE clause

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm working on a JavaEE application with EJB and I have these two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Utente implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int cod_utente;
private String nome_utente;
private String morada_utente;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private GregorianCalendar dnasc_utente;
private int tel_utente;
private List<GregorianCalendar> agenda;
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Entities.Prescricao.class,fetch=EAGER)
private List<Prescricao> lista_presc;
```

and

```
@Entity
public class FichaClinica implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int cod_ficha;
@OneToOne
private Utente cod_utente;
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Entities.AtoEnfermagem.class,fetch=EAGER)
private List <AtoEnfermagem> lista_atos_enf;
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Entities.AtoMedico.class,fetch=EAGER)
private List <AtoMedico> lista_atos_medicos;
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Entities.Consulta.class,fetch=EAGER)
private List<Consulta> lista_consultas;
```

I want to select the *FichaClinica* using a given *Utente*, so I'm using the following query (*em* is the *EntityManager*):

```
FichaClinica fc=(FichaClinica)em.createQuery("select object(fc) from FichaClinica fc where fc.cod_utente like :cod").setParameter("cod",u).getResultList().get(0);
```

But this isn't working. An error occurs:

> Syntax error: Encountered "LIKE"

Can please someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an non-detached instance of *Utente* and want to get the corresponding *FichaClinica*, consider adding the reverse side of the relationship in order to get a direct reference to it from the class *Utente*.

If you want to use JPQL, you cannot use *like* with entities. Use *=*:

```
select object(fc) from FichaClinica fc where fc.cod_utente = :cod
```